# Getting error when I am trying to run shell 'sed' command from python

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to remove new line characters from a file using sed command. I wrote a sed command sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' filename.
I runs fine and generate the expected result. But when I try to run this command using python.

```py
cmd="""sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' filename"""
os.system(cmd)
```

It throws a exception stating:
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated `s' command
256

Comment: Try printing out `cmd`; you might be surprised at what you see.

Comment: also why using `sed` when python does the job?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `\n` is the *newline character*, not a literal backslash followed by `n`. You can use raw strings to get the latter:

```
r"This is a backslash and an n: \n"
```